# elementary proof in set theory (by contradiction)

Tags: analysis, elementary-set-theory, logic

Define A := {r ϵ ℝ : 0 < r ≤ 1} and M_x := {t ϵ A: t < x} where x ϵ A.

Proposition. M_x ⊂ M_y ⇔ 0 < x ≤ y ≤ 1.

Proof. First we note that 0 < x ∧ 0 < y ∧ x ≤ 1 ∧ y ≤ 1 for anything to make sense. Thus it suffices to consider x ≤ y. Assume (M_x ⊂ M_y) ∧ (y < x). Then y < (y+x)/2 < x. Then (y+x)/2 ϵ M_x and (y+x)/2 ∉ M_y. ⊥. Thus M_x ⊂ M_y ⇒ x ≤ y. Now consider x ≤ y. Then (∀p ϵ M_x) (0 < p < y). That is to say, p ϵ M_x ⇒ p ϵ M_y ⇔ M_x ⊂ M_y. So x ≤ y ⇒ M_x ⊂ M_y. Thus M_x ⊂ M_y ⇔ 0 < x ≤ y ≤ 1.

Is the proof correct? I understand that ¬(y < x) ⇔ (x ≤ y) but x ≤ y means x = y or x < y. However, for all we know, ¬(y = x) can also be true, and  ¬(y < x) ∧ ¬(y = x) ⇔ (x < y). If it is not correct, then how does one prove the proposition?

Comment: Welcome Math.SE! Take the [tour](http://math.stackexchange.com/tour) to get familiar with this site. Mathematical expressions and equations can be [formatted](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) using $\LaTeX$ syntax.

Answer (score 1):

Here's half the argument. I recommend you utilize logic notation as another language, and assume that not everyone is fluent in that language. Therefore it is best to communicate without it, but for personal usages you can use it however you want.

Define $ A:= (0,1] $.
Define $ M_x:=\left\{t\in A:t<x\right\} $ for every $ x\in A $.

Proposition. $ M_x\subseteq M_y $ if and only if $ 0<x\le y\le 1 $.

Proof.

($ \Rightarrow $)
Assume $ M_x\subseteq M_y $.
By contradiction, suppose $ y<x $.
Therefore $ y\in M_x $.
Therefore $ y\in M_y $.
Therefore $ y<y $---a contradiction.
As a result, $ y\nless x $.
Because real numbers are totally ordered (i.e. for any two real numbers $ s,t $, exactly one of the following holds: $ s<t $, $ s=t $, $ s>t $), it can be concluded $ x\le y $.

Comment: English can be a second language too. It takes longer for me to read english mixed with math, than just math.

Comment: English is not my native language either, but First-Order Logic is no one's native language.

Comment: At least googling about this learnt me a new word: to calque.